# why am i getting file not found exception in phonegap although the file exists

Tags: java, android, cordova

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs){
    fs.root.getDirectory("folder1", {
      create : false
    },function(dataDir) {
      dataDir.getDirectory("folder2", {
        create : false
      },function(dataDir1) {
    dataDir1.getDirectory("folder3",{
      create : false 
    },function(dataDir2) {
          dataDir2.getDirectory("folder4",{
        create:false,
      },function(dataDir3) {
            var reader = dataDir3.createReader();
            reader.readEntries(function(entries){
        for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
                entries[i].file(function(file){
            alert(file.name);
            alert(file.fullPath);
          var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey="uploadFile";
options.fileName=file.name;
options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
var params = new Object();
  params.action = "uploadFile";   
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload((file.fullPath), "http://server.com/upload.pl", win, fail, options);
```

But this is giving java io exception of file not found. But the file is existing. What's wrong??
Any help??
It is giving error code 1 .http_status : 500 it is giving

Comment: Can you get the path from a breakpoint and see if it matches?

Comment: And you can see the file being there physically?

Comment: yeah it is there physically

Comment: The error 500 is because of internal error on the http call. So, could be the message "file not found" related to "http://server.com/upload.pl" instead of for file.fullPath? It's only an idea...

Comment: no... it is not related to server ... because it works in other similar cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now . There was a error in server side .
Thank u all..